# Convolutional networks: how to deal with duplicate filters?

Tags: correlation, neural-networks, convolution

I have to train a convolutional network. When I visualize its conv filter matrices from a layer, many filters are quite similar, almost equal.

1) Don't you know a common way to detect couples of similar kernels? Maybe, it is somehow connected with their correlation?

2) Don't you know any good strategies to deal with such duplicate kernels? My only offer is to re-initialize such duplicate with noise and continue the training, but I don't think it is the best idea.

Comment: How do you train the CNN? Layerwise as stacked RBMs or as stacked Autoencoders or something else?

Comment: I think reinitialization is quite a common technique, though certainly not the best. When you have sparse activity in the features, it is a bad idea to use correlation as a measure for similarity, since the fact that most features output zero means the features are correlated a bit by definition. You should rather have some measure on the weight vectors themselves. For example, you can look at the direction of the weight vectors and the length, or just look at the length of the difference between the weight vectors.